# Help with this formula I'm trying to make

Tags: algebra-precalculus

```
.75 - size * (n - 3) / steps
```

Assuming `b = 3`:

When assigning 3 to `n`, the formula will result in 0.75, `n = 4` will result in 0.5 and `n = 5` will result in 0.25. Which is exactly what I wanted.

Now, I want to add 2 parameters to this formula. `steps` and `size`.

If `steps = 2`, and `size = 0.25` (`b` is still 3), `n = 3` would result in 0.75 and `n = 5` would result in 0.5, and `n = 7` would result in 0.25. I hope you're following!

What steps should I make in order to successfully integrate these 2 parameters into my formula? Would that be possible or should I make a new formula?

I'm not a mathematician, at all.

Comment: What do you mean by 'results in' - are you trying to solve w.r.t. $a$? Are the two lines one equation?

Comment: I'm finding it hard to follow what you're after. Perhaps if you added some context it'd be easier to understand? Or make a table of $a,b,n,\text{steps},\text{size}$ with some example values so we can see the pattern you're after easier

Comment: @DominikS the result of the formula

Comment: I'm also not quite seeing what `size` is for

Comment: Perhaps try `0.75 - size * (n - 3) / steps`?

Comment: @Shuri2060 Thank you! size is how much the result decrements when you increment steps. In the formula as it is now, size seems to be 0.25, because n=3 results in 0.75, and n=4 results in 0.5.

Comment: @Shuri2060 you nailed it! thank you so much! maybe post this as an answer so i could give you points?

Comment: " I hope you're following!"  I can assure you nobody is.  You haven't described in any sense how steps modifies anything.  You merely state that if steps is 2 then the value for n=3 will be the same as it was when steps wasn't specified (but presumably set to some unknown value but that n=5 will have a different result whereas n =4 with no steps and n= with two steps are given with no value to compare.  Meanwhile size is not integrated or explained for any reason.  Why don't you actually try to tell us what the formula is supposed to *DO*?

Comment: At least one thing seems to be granted: $b$ is $3$ and remains $3$.

Comment: You should read your own post after forgetting all you know about the problem. You will realize that it is of the kind: "if $a=2$ and we don't use $\xi$, what is $v'$ ?"

Answer (score 0):

Something like this could work:

$$f(n,b,\text {steps},\text{size}) =
\begin{cases}
0.75,&& n=3,\text {steps}=0.25, \text{size}=0.5, b=3 \\\
0.5,&& n=5,\text {steps}=0.25, \text{size}=0.5, b=3  \\\
0.25,&& n=7,\text {steps}=0.25, \text{size}=0.5,b=3  \\\
0.75\times (2 - (n / b)), &&\text{otherwise} \\
\end{cases}$$